# FParsec Source Projects Won't Load in VS 2017

Tags: parsing, f#, visual-studio-2017, fparsec

I just got the FParsec source from Github and tried to open the solutions in Visual Studio 2017. I have the latest update to VS 2017, version 15.4.4, including Nuget Package Manager 4.4.0. I have both the .NET Desktop and .NET Core workflows installed.

I can open and build the "legacy" FParsec.sln in the /Build/VS11 folder. But when I try to open the "master" FParsec.sln in the root folder, VS 2017 fails to load the FParsec, FParsecCS, and Test projects. In each case the output windows says:

Could not load file or assembly 'NuGet.VisualStudio.Implementation, Version=4.4.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The FParsec documentation says "The solution file in the root source folder does not yet properly work within the Visual Studio 2017 IDE (due to incomplete support for F# in VS). However, the folder Build/VS11 contains a solution file that works with Visual Studio 2012 and later."

Microsoft announced yesterday that with the latest updates, VS 2017 supports F# in .NET Core and .NET Standard projects. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/15/announcing-f-support-for-net-core-and-net-standard-projects-in-visual-studio/

So I'm wondering if it's possible for me to fix this error now, or if the FParsec contributors have a timeline for resolving this.

Thank you.

Comment: The appropriate place to post this is FParsec's [repository on Github](https://github.com/stephan-tolksdorf/fparsec/), not SO. As for F# support, that's for Update 5 (ie 15.5) Preview 4, not Update 4 (15.4). Have you tried with 15.5? F# already worked with 15.5 Preview 3 but I guess they wanted to test it more

Comment: I did install the 15.5 Preview 4, but the About Visual Studio dialog still says I have 15.4. Sorry if any confusion. So I will post this on Github.